# How to customize the line in Android ICS-style dialogs

Tags: android, dialog, styles

How can I style the blue divider between the title and the content of a Dialog (see screenshot)?

I prefer to do it via xml, but if necessary I'll take a programmatic solution.

I've looked through the default styles.xml and themes.xml of android-15, but I couldn't find anything.

[image: Standard Android dialog]

Comment: did u got the desired solution??

Comment: I am wanting to do the same. What did you decide on in the end?

Comment: Made a custom Dialog, using a modified version of the AlertDialog resources (found here https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/layout). I'm sure there's a better way, but I didnt' find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ActionBarSherlock you can check it out by looking at abs_dialog_title_holo.xml. There you will see that the blue line is a devider that is defined through a view:

```
<View android:id="@+id/abs__titleDivider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="@color/abs__holo_blue_light" />
```

Comment: Thanks. So there's no way to customize this without changing parts of ABS?

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/title" style="?android:attr/windowTitleStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dip"
        android:paddingRight="16dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left" 
        android:text="Dialog"
        android:textColor="@Color/blue"/>
    <View android:id="@+id/titleDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="@Color/blue" />
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dip"
        android:paddingRight="16dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
        android:text="Your Text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

set this xml as content of the class and add below line in manifest file below activity:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: We'd like to keep the native ICS look, with just that line in a different color. But I guess I could base off of the default dialog layout...

Comment: @AkashG How do you "set this xml as content of the class"? which class are you referring to?  pls can you provide a coding example?  I'll gladly upvote this answer if you can help me make it work.

Comment: @PeteH you can set this by taking new activity and pass this layout in setContentView of the activity. And also in the answer i have written to set theme in manifest file also. You will surely be able to set your own custom dialog.

Comment: @AkashG: Thanks for your response. FYI, I'm using the ActionBar throughout my app.  Is there a theme option I can use that will allow the ActionBar *and* the custom dialogs? (`.NoTitleBar` is causing NPE for the ActionBar).